# wp_category map: id & name

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to develop a WordPress plugin that gets posts by category and displays them with javascript.

I need to display the category name.

I was thinking I could have php output an object of all categories: their id and their name in a single object.

I could then use this to translate a post's category ID to a name.

I tried doing this with:

```
'all_categories' => array_map(
     function ($fiteredCat) {
         return (object) [
             $fiteredCat->term_id => $fiteredCat->cat_name
         ];
      },
      array_filter($categories, function ($cat) {
         // exclude 21 & 1
         return $cat->term_id !== 21 && $cat->term_id !== 1;
      }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH))
```

but this is outputting

```
"all_categories" : {
    "0" : {
        "15" : Case Studies
    },
    "1" : {
        "17" : Events
    },
    "4" : {
        "13" : Useful Documents
    },
    "5" : {
        "3" : videos
    },
    "6" : {
        "16" : Webinars
    },
    "7" : {
        12" : White Papers
    }
}
```

How can I use PHP to get this?:

```
"all_categories" : {
    "15": "Case Studies",
    "17": "Events",
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$post_categories = [];

 array_walk(array_filter($categories, function ($cat) { 
     // exclude 21 & 1 
     return $cat->term_id !== 21 && $cat->term_id !== 1;
 }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH), 
 function ($fiteredCat) use(&$post_categories){ 
     $post_categories[$fiteredCat->term_id] = $fiteredCat->cat_name; 
 }); 

 echo json_encode(['post_categories' => $post_categories]);
```

Comment: You are the man! thanks!  you don't know how to format your answer, but you got the code right! :)  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you return this

```
"post_categories" : {
    "15": "Case Studies",
    "17": "Events",
    ....
}
```

to javascript, you would not be able to loop through the individual categories.
I suggest that you either use multi-dimensional arrays or you have an array of objects.

**Multi-dimensional Array**
`[["15","Case Studies"],["17","Events"]]`

then in your javascript, you can loop through the array with any loop you would prefer

```
returned_array.forEach((arr)=>{
  let key = arr[0];
  let value = arr[1];
  //Then you can do what you want with the data
})
```

**Array of Objects**
`[{"15":"Case Studies"},{"17":"Events"}]`

then you do basically the same thing you loop through your array

```
returned_array.forEach((obj)=>{
  let key = Object.keys(obj);
  let value = obj[key];
  //Then you can do what you want with the data
})
```

hope this helps you

Comment: I was just going to use `categories[cat_id]` to get the value in js.  no need to loop.  I just don't know how to get the php to get it the way I want it

Comment: Are you doing it for just one category? if **no** then you have to loop through all categories otherwise i might have another suggestion.

Comment: in a loop (in js) i'll be looping through posts returned from a search.  for each post, i'll convert the categories[0], which will be an id, into a name by doing a `categories_from_php_object[categories[0]]` for example if the post's first category is 15, i'd essentially be doing `categories_from_php[15]` to get 'Case Studies"

Comment: Then that means your post category would be an array, not an object? Hope I'm getting you right?

Comment: yes, post's categories are arrays.  I just need to label one of them, so I'm going to use the first one "[0]".  I just need to translate that into a name without another call to the api.  I'd like to have an object in js to use as a translator.  just can't get the object the way I want to using php.

Comment: i updated the question to avoid confusion.  i'm trying to get a map of ALL categories done in PHP